# Prolog check if function "returned" no?

Tags: function, syntax, prolog

I'm new to prolog.  This is a hypothetical question - I realize it has no practical use.  But I'm trying to figure out how to get Prolog to behave one way if a "no" return is received, and another if a "yes" is received.

I'm trying to write a function `gothrough` that takes a list, checks to see if the head of the list is equal to ',' and if it is, passes it to another function `checkit`. `checkit` checks to see if that passed variable is equal to ';'.  If it is, it returns yes.  If not, it returns no.  I want `gothrough` to understand this return value and act accordingly.  I understand that prolog doesn't actually return values, but I don't really know how else to describe what I want to do....
So I have this so far:

```
 checkit(H):- H==';'.
 gothrough([H|T]):- H==',', checkit(H), /*what do put here?  if/else statement depending on return value of checkit*/
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the way you are calling `checkit/1` will always fail, as `H` is already bound to `','` so it clearly cannot unify with `';'` at the same time.

Now, regarding your if-then-else question, use [->/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=send_arrow/2) control predicate:

```
gothrough([H|T]):- 
   H==',', 
   (checkit(H) -> 
         writeln(true_part) ; 
         writeln(false_part)
   ).
```